# Node js + mongoose, out of memory, takes too much time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory, mongoose, time-complexity

so I have this problem. I am using node js + mongoose, to try to recommend a movie to a user. The math behind is quite simple, you check what other users has rated a movie compared to you, to find the people who is similar to you, then you use that to predict the rating of a certain movie. You do that for all the movies and then recommend the one with the highest predicted rating. In my database I already got 100 k ratings, with 1,6 k movies and around 950 users (got the dataset from movielens). I have a model for Ratings which has movieid, title, value, and user. Using the code below, I can predict one movie, however, when I try to predict all the 1,k6 movies by using a loop, I get this msg "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory". I guess the way I've implemented takes up too much memory. It also takes alot of time. Around 3-4 sec to predict one movie, which means around 100 min to predict all 1,6k movies. Does anyone have any suggestion for improvements? Im quite new to nodejs and this asynchronous environment is making me uncomfortable.
Heres my code:

```
Rating.find({title:"Batman Forever (1995)"}, function(err,rating){
    if (err) throw err;
    var tempSimilarValues = [];
    var count = 0;
    Rating.find({user: userV}, function(err,result) {
        var tempMovieV;
        var tempRatingArrayV = [];
        var tempMovieArrayV = [];
        while (result.length>0) {
            tempMovieV=result.pop();
            tempMovieArrayV.push(tempMovieV.movieid);
            tempRatingArrayV.push(tempMovieV.value);
        }
        //calculating averageRatingV
        var ratingV;
        var avarageRatingV=0;
        var countV=0;
        for(ratingV in tempRatingArrayV){
            countV++;
            avarageRatingV=avarageRatingV+tempRatingArrayV[ratingV];
        }
        avarageRatingV=avarageRatingV/countV;
        rating.forEach(function(obj){
            Rating.find({user: obj.user}, function(err,result2) {

                var tempRatingArray = [];
                var tempMovieArray = [];
                var tempMovie;
                var tempAverage=0;
                var ammount = result2.length
                while (result2.length>0) {
                    tempMovie=result2.pop();

                    tempMovieArray.push(tempMovie.movieid);
                    tempAverage=tempAverage+tempMovie.value
                    tempRatingArray.push(tempMovie.value);

                }

                var averageU=tempAverage/ammount;
                var similar = calSim(tempRatingArrayV,tempRatingArray, tempMovieArrayV, tempMovieArray);

                if(obj.user!=userV){
                    tempSimilarValues.push([similar,obj.user,obj.value,averageU]);
                }

                count++;

                if(count == rating.length){


                    tempSimilarValues.sort(function (a,b){
                        if (a[0] > b[0]) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        if (a[0] < b[0]) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        // a must be equal to b
                        return 0;

                    });

                    var similarValues=tempSimilarValues.slice(0,k);
                    var similarity;
                    var teller=0;
                    var nevner=0;
                    for (similarity in similarValues){
                        teller=teller+similarValues[similarity][0]*(similarValues[similarity][2]-similarValues[similarity][3]);
                        nevner = nevner + similarValues[similarity][0];
                    }

                    var pred = avarageRatingV + teller/nevner;
                    console.log(pred);
                }
            })
        })

    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using callbacks for nesting code of multiple methods will make you end up with the **[Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/)**. A better way of handling your scenario is to use the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** library, particularly its **[`series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** and **[`waterfall()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback)** methods.

To illustrate this with a similar short example which performs similar multiple operations with callbacks to find ratings that belong to a user (code one),  find some ratings belonging to a certain title (code two), calculate average rating (code three) and then calculate the one with the highest predicted rating (code four):

```
codeOne(function(a){
    codeTwo(function(b){    
        codeThree(function(c){
            codeFour(function(d){
                // Final callback code        
            })
        })       

    })
})
```

Applying the **[`series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** method which runs the tasks array of functions in series, each one running once the previous function has completed. If any functions in the series pass an error to its callback, no more functions are run, and callback is immediately called with the value of the error. Otherwise, callback receives an array of results when tasks have completed.:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // code one
        callback(null, 'one')
    },
    function(callback){
        // code two
        callback(null, 'two')
    },
    function(callback){
        // code three
        callback(null, 'three')
    },
    function(callback){
        // code four
        callback(null, 'four')
    }],
    // optional callback
    function(err, results){
        // results is ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
        // final callback code
    }
)
```

Applying the **[`waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback)** method which runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the error.:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        // code one
        callback(null, 'one', 'two')
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        // arg1 is equals 'one' and arg2 is 'two'
        // code three
        callback(null, 'three')
    },
    function(arg1, callback){      
        // arg1 is 'three'
        // code four
        callback(null, 'four');
    }], function (err, result) {
        // result is 'four'    
    }
)
```

In your example code, would suggest restructuring it to use the waterfall method. Here's my attamept at implementing your logic using the async library, not 100% certain of what you are trying to achieve so this might not work but you may get the concept:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        // code one - calculate the average rating for user
        Rating.find({user: userV}, function(err,result) {
            if (err) callback(err);         

            var ratingV,
                avarageRatingV = 0,
                countV = 0,
                tempRatingArray = result.map(function(rating){
                    return rating.value;
                }),
                tempMovieArrayV = result.map(function(rating){
                    return rating.movieid;
                });

            //calculating averageRatingV            
            for(ratingV in tempRatingArrayV){
                countV++;
                avarageRatingV = avarageRatingV + tempRatingArrayV[ratingV];
            }
            avarageRatingV=avarageRatingV/countV;
            callback(null, avarageRatingV, tempRatingArrayV, tempMovieArrayV);
        })
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, arg3, callback){
        // arg1 equals averageRatingV 
        // arg2 equals tempRatingArrayV
        // arg3 equals tempMovieArrayV
        // code to return the users for "Batman Forever (1995)" movie ratings
        Rating.find({ title: "Batman Forever (1995)" }, function(err, ratings){
            if (err) callback(err);
            var users = ratings.map(function(r){ return r.user; });
            callback(null, arg1, arg2, arg3, users);
        });         
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, callback){      
        // arg1 is averageRatingV, 
        // arg2 equals tempRatingArrayV, 
        // arg3 equals tempMovieArrayVis ratings 
        // arg4 is the users array for "Batman Forever (1995)" movie ratings
        // code to return
        Rating.find({"user": { "$in": arg4 }}, function(err, result) {
            // do the necessary calculations here
            callback(null, result);
        });
    }], function (err, result) {
        // final result   
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thx for the feedback. Although it didnt work, I got the point and it helped. However, is it possible to have this async.waterfall to return something? It would be nice if I could have this inside a function.

Comment: @user3799968 Mongoose's `find()` method is asynchronous and thus can finish at any time, so creating functions that return a variable from an async operation will not work since values are undefined when you're accessing them. You need to understand how asynchronous operations work. In your case, use the `async.waterfall()` callback which runs once all the functions have completed to then access the result. This will be passed the results of the last task's callback.